# `appendChild(htmlobject)` only append the last child form an array of data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a shopping cart and will load the products of inside the cart after a `XMLHttpRequest`. Because the complexity of the table rows I've extracted this inside my HTML code *(in code below see: `#sampleBody`)*. This contains the default markup of the row.

When I've done the request, I take the `sampleBody` and will append them to the `cartBody`. This I'll do alter every loop in over `data`. The problem is that only the first element is visible *(I'm looping backwards)*.

**P.S.:** In code below I've just add the code what happens after the request.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var sampleBody, cartBody;
  var data = [{
    name: "product 1",
    price: 15,
    quantity: 2,
    total: 30
  }, {
    name: "name of product 2",
    price: 10,
    quantity: 3,
    total: 30
  }]

  function init() {
    sampleBody = document.getElementById('sampleBody');
    cartBody = document.getElementById('cartBody');
  }

  init();

  var renderCart = function(data) {
    var html = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i = data.length; i--;) {

      sampleBody.querySelector('#name').innerText = data[i].name;
      sampleBody.querySelector('#price').innerText = data[i].price;
      sampleBody.querySelector('#quantity').value = data[i].quantity;
      sampleBody.querySelector('#total').innerText = data[i].total;
      html.appendChild(sampleBody);
    }

    while (cartBody.firstChild) {
      cartBody.removeChild(cartBody.firstChild);
    }

    cartBody.appendChild(html);
  };
  
  renderCart(data);

})();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="cartBody">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Loading...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="hidden">
  <tr id="sampleBody">
    <td id="name"></td>
    <td>€<span id="price"></span></td>
    <td>
      <button>+</button>
      <input type="text" id="quantity">
      <button>-</button>
    </td>
    <td>€<span id="total"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: appendChild removes an element from its current position if it is already in the DOM, and inserts it at the new one. You need to create _clones_ of your sampleBody element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clone your sampleBody node in your foor loop statement:

```
for (var i = data.length; i--;) {
    var node = sampleBody.cloneNode(true);
    node.setAttribute('id', node.getAttribute('id')+i);
    node.querySelectorAll('*[id]').forEach(elt => 
       elt.setAttribute('id', elt.getAttribute('id')+i)
    );
    node.querySelector('#name'+i).innerText = data[i].name;
    node.querySelector('#price'+i).innerText = data[i].price;
    node.querySelector('#quantity'+i).value = data[i].quantity;
    node.querySelector('#total'+i).innerText = data[i].total;
    html.appendChild(node);
}
```

We can also remove the ids and replace them by a name attribute:

HTML:

```
<table class="hidden">
  <tr name="sampleBody">
    <td name="name"></td>
    <td>€<span name="price"></span></td>
    <td>
      <button>+</button>
      <input type="text" name="quantity">
      <button>-</button>
    </td>
    <td>€<span name="total"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

JS:

```
...

function init() {
    sampleBody = document.querySelector('table.hidden > tr[name="sampleBody"]');
    cartBody = document.getElementById('cartBody');
}

...

for (var i = data.length; i--;) {
    var node = sampleBody.cloneNode(true);
    node.querySelector('*[name="name"]').innerText = data[i].name;
    node.querySelector('*[name="price"]').innerText = data[i].price;
    node.querySelector('*[name="quantity"]').value = data[i].quantity;
    node.querySelector('*[name="total"]').innerText = data[i].total;
    html.appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: You're totally right. I will update my answer to promote a valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `id` attribute values should be unique in valid HTML. So you should not use `id` for what you are doing. You can use `class` for this instead, and then filter for the one you want to assign the text to, like this:

```
for (var i = data.length; i--;) {
  sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.name')[i].innerText = data[i].name;
  sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.price')[i].innerText = data[i].price;
  sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.quantity')[i].value = data[i].quantity;
  sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.total')[i].innerText = data[i].total;
  html.appendChild(sampleBody);
}
```

It would in fact be more efficient to perform those 4  `querySelectorAll` once, before the loop:

```
var names = sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.name');
var prices = sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.price');
var quantities = sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.quantity');
var totals = sampleBody.querySelectorAll('.total');
for (var i = data.length; i--;) {
  names[i].innerText = data[i].name;
  prices[i].innerText = data[i].price;
  quantities[i].value = data[i].quantity;
  totals[i].innerText = data[i].total;
  html.appendChild(sampleBody);
}
```